# Can't write to writeonly Shader Storage Block

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Part of the geometry shader code looks like this:

```
layout(std430) restrict coherent buffer BufferName
{
     uint bufferName[][MAX_EXPECTED_ENTRIES];
};

...

void main()
{   
... 
bufferName[a][b] = someValue;
...
}
```

Everything works as expected until I add a `writeonly` statement to either `BufferName`, `bufferName` or both.
With the `writeonly` statement I get the following error: `error C7586: OpenGL does not allow reading writeonly variable 'bufferName'`.

What's going on here?
All I do is writing to `bufferName` and the [spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_storage_buffer_object.txt) says that `writeonly` is allowed. This also happens for one-dimensional arrays within a storage block.

Thanks in advance.

---

Here's the full shader code (`BufferName` from the example is now `IDsPerVertex`):

```
#version 450
#define MAX_EXPECTED_VERTEX_PRIMITIVE_IDS 10

layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

layout(std430) restrict coherent buffer IDsPerVertex
{
     uint iDsPerVertex[][MAX_EXPECTED_VERTEX_PRIMITIVE_IDS];
};

layout(std430) restrict coherent buffer Counter
{
    uint counter[];
};

in int ID[3]; // contains gl_VertexID
out vec4 debugColor;

uint index[3];

void writeIDsPerVertex()
{
    // get the next free location for each vertex
    index[0] = atomicAdd(counter[ID[0]], 1u);
    index[1]  = atomicAdd(counter[ID[1]], 1u);
    index[2]  = atomicAdd(counter[ID[2]], 1u);

    // write the triangle primitive ID to each vertex list
    iDsPerVertex[ID[0]][index[0]] = gl_PrimitiveIDIn;
    iDsPerVertex[ID[1]][index[1]] = gl_PrimitiveIDIn;
    iDsPerVertex[ID[2]][index[2]] = gl_PrimitiveIDIn;
}

void passThrough()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++)
    {
        gl_Position = projection * view * model * gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        debugColor = vec4(1);
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EndPrimitive();
}

void main()
{
    writeIDsPerVertex();
    passThrough();
}
```

---

The full error message my environment gives me:

```
SHADER PROGRAM 37 LOG
Geometry info
-------------
(0) : error C7586: OpenGL does not allow reading writeonly variable 'iDsPerVertex'
```

Comment: "*All I do is writing to bufferName*" And yet GLSL seems to think you're not. Perhaps you could post the actual shader in full. Also, if the buffer is write-only, why does it need to be coherent? Or rather more to the point, with what exactly is it being coherent?

Comment: Another shaderprogram is executed after this one, which reads from that SSBO. So it should be coherent to make the writes visible?

Comment: And you're certain that the error is talking about `iDsPerVertex`? Please post the error message you get when you make it `writeonly`.

Comment: "*Another shaderprogram is executed after this one, which reads from that SSBO.*" The only possible shader that could receive `iDsPerVertex` within the same draw command are the FS invocations that execute for the primitives generated by this GS. And [they can be passed `gl_PrimitiveID` from the GS](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Outputs); you don't need to use a storage buffer for it. So you're either using an SSBO unnecessarily or using an SSBO *incorrectly*.

Comment: Sorry, with shaderprogram I mean another program, linked by OpenGL.
Renderpass might be the better term for that.

Comment: Then `coherent` [isn't helping.](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Incoherent_Memory_Access) `coherent` is for ensuring `coherent` accesses between dependent shader invocations. Shader invocations in different rendering commands are *never* dependent; you have to use an explicit memory barrier to ensure such visibility.